# Whose basis is {1,sin(x),cos(x),sin(2x),cos(2x),…}?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Whenever $f(x)$ is a (Riemann) integrable function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ we can define its Fourier series $f=a_0/2+\sum a_nsin(nx)+b_ncos(nx)$.But we give arbitrary sequence {$a_n$} and {$b_n$},I think $a_0/2+\sum a_nsin(nx)+b_ncos(nx)$ may not be integrable.Then let $R$={$f(x)|f(x)$ is Riemann integrable },$S$=span{1,sin(x),cos(x),sin(2x),cos(2x),…},one have $R\subset$S.We know {1,sin(x),cos(x),sin(2x),cos(2x),…} is a basis,but which space it is the basis for?

Comment: It's an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space of square-integrable (in the Lebesgue sense) functions on $[\pi, pi]$.

Comment: Thank you very much.And you mean $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. Is it identical under the real and complex situation?

Comment: Hilbert spaces are usually assumed to be complex. Elements with real coefficients then become a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this basis as a basis for various spaces, not just $L^2$.

A general way to build a complete normed function space is to:

1. Think up a norm, like $\sup |f|$, or $\sup |f|+\sup |f'|$, or $\int |f|$, or $\sqrt{\int |f|^2 }$, or maybe $|f(0)|+\sqrt{\int e^{-x^2}|f'(x)|^2}$...
2. Pick a bunch of functions $f_n$ with finite norm.
3. Take the (algebraic) linear span of those functions, i.e., the set of all finite linear combinations. The elements of this set still have finite norm. The norm defines a metric on the set.
4. Take the completion of the set obtained in 3.
5. You have a function space, in which the functions picked at step 2 form a *spanning set*.
6. If you want them to be a *basis*, understood as [Schauder basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis), there is one more thing to  check: you must be able to approximate any element of the space by  *partial sums of a series* $\sum c_n f_n$, not just by some sequence of linear combinations. The series should be unique, too.

You can go through steps 1-5 using trigonometric functions in 2 and pretty much any norm imaginable. At step 6 some norms will be disqualified. For example, you get a basis in $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, but not for $L^1$ (see the Wikipedia article).